# Catching specific category of warnings in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use the approach suggested [in Python's official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#testing-warnings) to catch warnings and log them in a user-friendly manner:

```
import logging
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warning(record=True) as wlist:
     warnings.simplefilter("always", UserWarning)
     # do something that may `warn`

     for w in wlist:
          logging.warning("<some nice message> (%s)", w.message)
```

However, I would like to only catch-and-log warnings of a specific category (e.g., `UserWarning`).  I could test the `category` attribute and ignore the other warnings in logging, i.e., replace the lines inside the `for` block by:

```
        if issubclass(w.category, UserWarning):
            logging.warning(...) # as before
```

But now all the other warnings are totally suppressed.  Is there a way/trick to limit the `catch_warning` to only specific category of warnings?

---

UPDATE: I found some way that is close to a good solution but still not perfect:

```
import logging
import warnings

import sys


def func(val):
    if val < 0.5:
        warnings.warn("`val` smaller than 0.5")


    return val - 0.5

def dep(s):
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)

    return s

def run():
    vals = [0.1, 0.2, 1]


    for i, val in enumerate(vals):
        print("S"*64)
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            warnings.simplefilter("always", UserWarning)
            print(dep(func(val)))
            print(dep(func(-val)))

            for warning in w:
                if issubclass(warning.category, UserWarning):
                    logging.warning("Caught %s on value at index %d: %s",
                                    warning.category, i, warning.message)
                else:
                    sys.stderr.write(
                        warnings.formatwarning(warning.message,
                                               warning.category,
                                               warning.filename,
                                               warning.lineno,
                                               line=warning.line)
                    )


        print("E"*64)
        print('\n\n')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
    run()
```

Running the above gives the following output:

```
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
-0.4
-0.6
WARNING:root:Caught <class 'UserWarning'> on value at index 0: `val` smaller than 0.5
warncatch.py:34: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(val)))
WARNING:root:Caught <class 'UserWarning'> on value at index 0: `val` smaller than 0.5
warncatch.py:35: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(-val)))
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE



SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
-0.3
-0.7
WARNING:root:Caught <class 'UserWarning'> on value at index 1: `val` smaller than 0.5
warncatch.py:34: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(val)))
WARNING:root:Caught <class 'UserWarning'> on value at index 1: `val` smaller than 0.5
warncatch.py:35: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(-val)))
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE



SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
0.5
-1.5
warncatch.py:34: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(val)))
WARNING:root:Caught <class 'UserWarning'> on value at index 2: `val` smaller than 0.5
warncatch.py:35: DeprecationWarning: deprecated
  print(dep(func(-val)))
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

In each iteration of the `for` loop, I get the behavior that I want.  `UserWarning`s are turned into a warning message in the logger (`logging.warn`), and other warnings are treated as they would've been treated by default.  (To test, we can change `stacklevel=2` to `stacklevel=1`) in `dep()` routine and see that only one `DeprecationWarning` is issued in each iteration of the for loop.)

However, what is still incorrect is that the two `DeprecationWarning`s are repeated in successive iterations of the `for` loop, whereas, without any of my warning-catching fixtures, the code would've reported only two `DeprecationWarning`s.

Any ideas and helps to fix this last issue would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: I guess this might be helpful to you https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Comment: @DeepBhatt Thank you, but I've gone through the documentation and have not found a solution.  (As I wrote in the question, my approach is indeed based on what has been proposed in the documentation page you mentioned.)